# Why different behaviour of synthesized default constructor for static and local variable of user defined class type?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

In the sample program below,

Why is the output different for static & automatic variable of user defined class type ?

```
/* test.cpp */

/* SalesData Class */
class SalesData {

    public:
        SalesData() = default;
        // other member funcations
    private:
        std::string bookNo;
        unsigned int unitsSold;
        double revenue;

};

/*
 * Prints the SalesData object
 */
std::ostream& print(std::ostream &os, const SalesData &item) {
    os << "ISBN :\'" << item.isbn() << "\', Units Sold :" << item.unitsSold
        << ", Revenue :" << item.revenue << ", Avg. Price :"
        << item.avgPrice() << std::endl;

    return os;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SalesData s;
    static SalesData s2;


    print(cout, s);
    print(cout, s2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output of the program is this --

```
$ ./test
ISBN :'', Units Sold :3417894856, Revenue :4.66042e-310, Avg. Price :1.36352e-319
ISBN :'', Units Sold :0, Revenue :0, Avg. Price :0
```

How is static changing the scene in synthesized default constructor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default constructor has the same behavior on `s` and `s2`. The difference is, for [static local variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables),

> Variables declared at block scope with the specifier static `or thread_local (since C++11)` have static `or thread (since C++11)` storage duration but are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration (unless their initialization is [zero-](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) or constant-initialization, which can be performed before the block is first entered).

and about [zero-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization):

> For every named variable with static `or thread-local (since C++11)` storage duration that is not subject to constant initialization, before any other initialization.

That means `s2` will be zero-initialized firstly, as the effect its data members are zero-initialized too; then enterning `main()` it's default-initialized via the default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

##### Case I

Lets consider `SalesData s;` .

In this case an object of type `SalesData` with name `s` is constructed using the **default constructor** of `SalesData`. Also, note that in this case the variable `s` is a **local nonstatic**.

Next since you :

1. **didn't** Use in-class initializers to initialize `unitsSold` and `revenue`
2. **didn't** Use **constructor initializer list** to initialize `unitsSold` and `revenue`

These 2 variables hold **indeterminate value**. And using these uninitialized variables leads to **undefined behavior**.

This means when you wrote:

```
print(cout, s);//this calls print function
```

And inside the `print` function's body you have:

```
os << "ISBN :\'" << item.isbn() << "\', Units Sold :" << item.unitsSold
        << ", Revenue :" << item.revenue << ", Avg. Price :"
        << item.avgPrice() << std::endl; //this is undefined behavior
```

So in the above statement you're using the **uninitialized** variables `unitsSold` and `revenue` and this results in **undefined behavior**.

> Undefined behavior means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

This is the reason you saw those numbers(garbage values) like `3417894856` and `4.66042e-310` in this case. So don't rely on the output of your program since it has undefined behavior.

##### Case II

Now lets consider `static SalesData s2;`

From [Static local variables' initialization documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables):

> Variables declared at block scope with the specifier **static** or thread_local (*since C++11*) have static or thread (*since C++11*) storage duration but are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration (unless their initialization is **zero- or constant-initialization**, which can be performed before the block is first entered).

Now from [zero initialization documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization):

> Zero initialization is performed in the following situations:

> 1. For every named variable with static or thread-local (since C++11) storage duration that is not subject to constant initialization, before any other initialization.

Here comes the most relevant part:

The *effects of zero initialization* are:

> If T is an non-union **class type**, all base classes and **non-static data members are zero-initialized**, and all padding is initialized to zero bits. The constructors, if any, are ignored.

Lets apply these above quoted statements to your example `static SalesData s2;`

In this case the variable `s2` is a **local static**. Here 2 things happen:

1. the variable `s2` is zero initialized. This means all of its non-static data members like `unitsSold` and `revenue` are set to `0` according to the above quoted statement. This is the reason the output numbers in this case are all `0` **instead of** some garbage values.
2. Next the variable `s2` is **default initialized** using the **default constructor**.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Variables with static storage duration are zero-initialised before their dynamic initialisation phase.

`unitsSold` and `revenue` are default initialised. That leaves them uninitialised. In the case of static storage, the previous zero initialisation holds. In the case of automatic storage, they have an indeterminate value. Reading the indeterminate value results in undefined behaviour of the program.